# NullPointerException при создании Foreground Service

Tags: android

Пытаюсь сделать онлайн радио. Суть такая что при переходе с главного активити открывается Player (активити) и начинает играть радио (в сервисе), при этом в сервисе создается уведомление с кнопкой Стоп. Так вот при открытии этого самого Player приложение падает и выбрасывается исключение что обращается к несуществующему объекту. Подскажите как исправить ситуацию. Не могу понять почему возникает ошибка.

PS Я вообще в правильном направлении иду? пытаюсь из двух проектов переделать свое приложение

Вот мой код сервиса

```
public class PlayerService extends Service {

    public static Context context;
    boolean isPause = true;

    String stream;
    String radio;
    String img;

    private void showNotification() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
        closeIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pCloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, closeIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("AAAAAAAAAAAAA")
                .setTicker("BBBBBBBBBBBBB")
                .setContentText("CCCCCCCCC")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, "Стоп", pCloseIntent)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
        startForeground(PlayerConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID.PLAYER_SERVICE_ID, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        context = this;

        stream = intent.getExtras().getString("stream");
        radio = intent.getExtras().getString("radio");
        img = intent.getExtras().getString("img");

        if (intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            isPause = true;
            showNotification();
            ExoPlayer.startExoPlayer(stream, this);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            ExoPlayer.stopExoPlayer();
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Вот код Player

```
public class Player extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private String stream;
    private String radio;
    private int img;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ***

        stream = getIntent().getExtras().getString("stream").toString().trim();
        radio = getIntent().getExtras().getString("radio").toString().trim();
        img = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("img");

        startService(new Intent(this, PlayerService.class).putExtra("stream", stream));
        startService(new Intent(this, PlayerService.class).putExtra("radio", radio));
        startService(new Intent(this, PlayerService.class).putExtra("img", img));

        startPlayerService();
    }

    public void startPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Player.this, PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

Класс констант

```
public class PlayerConstants {
    public interface ACTION {
        public static String MAIN_ACTION = "myapps.onlineradio.action.main";
        public static String STOP_ACTION = "myapps.onlineradio.action.stop";
        public static String STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION = "myapps.onlineradio.action.startforeground";
        public static String STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION = "myapps.onlineradio.action.stopforeground";
    }

    public interface NOTIFICATION_ID {
        public static int PLAYER_SERVICE_ID = 101;
    }
}
```

Класс ExoPlayer //для управления самим плеером

```
public class ExoPlayer {
    static BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;
    static TrackSelector trackSelector;
    static SimpleExoPlayer player;

    public static void startExoPlayer(String url, Context context) {
        if (player != null) {
            player.stop();
        }

        bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory streamSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(streamSelectionFactory);

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector, new DefaultLoadControl());
        Uri streamUri = Uri.parse(url);
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "yourApplicationName"), bandwidthMeter);
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

        if (url.contains("m3u8")) {
            MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(streamUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
            player.prepare(mediaSource);
        } else {
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(streamUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
            player.prepare(mediaSource);
        }

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    public static void stopExoPlayer() {
        player.stop();
    }
}
```

Сам эксепшн

```
Process: myapps.onlineradio, PID: 2561
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service myapps.onlineradio.PlayerService@a997079 with Intent { cmp=myapps.onlineradio/.PlayerService (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3314)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at myapps.onlineradio.PlayerService.onStartCommand(PlayerService.java:50)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3297)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

ругается на строку

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION))
```

Comment: Постарайтесь привести минимально воспроизводимый пример, указать в каком месте возникает исключительная ситуация и приложите стектрейс.

Comment: Да, я забыл вписать стектрейс. Обновил вопрос

Comment: Вероятнее всего `intent.getAction()` возвращает `null` 
используйте Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION) дабы еще проверять ссылку на null

Comment: Вероятнее всего) но только я не могу понять почему

Comment: написал так, ругается на equals типа так можно писать только с 19 апи, а у меня приложение для андроид от 16 апи. Как-то иначе можно написать? Это условие я переписал как в другом проекте, но у меня не работает почему-то(

Comment: При чем здесь апи? Этот метод есть в языке с 7й версии. Какая версия у вас? Можете переписать так `if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION))`

Comment: наверное у меня 6 я настройки проекта не менял. Вроде заработало. Спасибо. Только можете пояснить почему без доп. условия не сработало?

Answer (score 2):

При использовании следующей конструкции

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION))
```

Может возникнуть ситуация когда `intent.getAction() == null`, при условии что `intent != null`
При возникновении такой ситуации возникает исключение потому что нельзя вызвать метод у `null` а именно это и постарается сделать ваша программа

```
if (null.equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION))
```

Начиная с Java 7, используйте

```
Objects.equals(intent.getAction(),PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)
```

Или же сами проверяйте на наличие ссылки.

```
if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGR‌​OUND_ACTION))
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: а еще можно так: `if(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction()))`, тогда проверять на `null` не надо будет